# Workday: Submit_Customer_Invoice returning an error - The task submitted is not authorized

Tags: data-integration, workday-api, snaplogic

I'm using Snaplogic to load records into workday. Trying to load invoices into workday using the object Submit_Customer_Invoice of web service Revenue_Management. I'm getting the following error:

```
"error": "Processing error occurred. The task submitted is not authorized."
```

[image: Task submitted is not authorized]

The documentation for workday is not helpful.

Does this error occur if I mess up the SOAP call or is it an access issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an access issue.  The user you are making requests with does not have the correct permissions.

When I was working with an implementation team and we switched to a different tenant that error started popping up.  The Workday implementer went into that tenant, tweaked some security settings (Sorry, not on the workday side so don't know where or what) and the service calls started working again.

Comment: Yes. Confirmed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else getting errors, you can run the task Security Analysis for Action in the tenant, select the webservice request in the Action dropdown, and then select an account that has access to that service (like an impl account, you don't need to have access to the account) and click Show Details.  This will give you a list of all the security Domains you need to add to the account to process the request.